# Matrix of timedeltas in pandas (pairwise)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have two pandas Series:

```
A = pd.Series(['2020-01-01 00:10:00', '2020-01-01 02:20:00'], dtype=pd.datetime64)
B = pd.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 02:30:00', '2020-01-01 03:00:00', dtype=pd.datetime64)
```

What is the fastest way to get a matrix (pandas DataFrame or numpy 2D array) of absolute values of timedeltas (in minutes) between each datetimes in two Series paiwise?

The result should be similar to this table:

```
10  | 140 | 170
140 |  10 |  40
```

Is there any function for this or the only option is to make a double for-cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert Series to numpy array, subtract with broadcasting with convert output to absolutu values with divide for final 2d array:

```
A = pd.Series(['2020-01-01 00:10:00', '2020-01-01 02:20:00'])
B = pd.Series(['2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-01 02:30:00', '2020-01-01 03:00:00'])
    
A = pd.to_datetime(A)
B = pd.to_datetime(B)
           
a = A.to_numpy()[:, None] - B.to_numpy()
a = np.abs(a) / (60 * 10 ** 9)
print (a)

[[ 10 140 170]
 [140  10  40]]
```

Comment: Great answer! Would you explain what is (60 * 10 ** 9), please?

Comment: @doktr - sure, difference is in nanoseconds, so for convert to minutes is used divide by `(60 * 10 ** 9)`